# Size of subplots in loop: Python

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, size, subplot

I have a loop generating a varying amount of subplots in a (nx3) pattern, where n is increasing relative to amount of subplots. I want to fix the size of every subplot (all of equal size), to be sure they are outputted nicely.

My code is part of a larger script but here's is the subplotting loop:

```
for i in range(len(iters)):                                             # range(amount of iterations)
            iter = int(iters[i])

            plt.subplot(n, 3, i+1)
            # plotting and scaling accordingly to iteration:
            scaleFactor = frac**(len(iters)-i-1)
            plt.plot(points[0, :iter]/scaleFactor, points[1, :iter]/scaleFactor, 'b-', linewidth=1)
            plt.xlim([0, 1])
            plt.ylim([-0.25, 0.525])
            plt.title('Iteration %i' %i)
            plt.xlabel('x')
            plt.ylabel('y')
     
      plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the gridspec package before? It gives pretty good control over the size and spacing of subplots. You start by defining the grid object (`gs`) then just pick out the part of the grid you want to work with in the call to `add_subplot`.

```py
from matplotlib import gridspec

iters = 'abcdefghijklmnop' ### left image in example output

### right image in example output
# iters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' 

rows = int(len(iters)/3)+1
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 1.2*rows))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(rows, 3, wspace=0.25, hspace=0.45)

for i in range(len(iters)):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[i])
    ax.plot([1,2], [2,1])
plt.show()
```

[image]